# Getting datatable filter lists in a single SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a page that lists records in a table. In the header of the table, we have filters that filter out the records for the selected values. In order to populate those filter lists, I need to get distinct values from the database. For example when listing employees of a company let us say I have filters for name, age, salary, then I have there separate queries like

```
select distinct name from employee where company = `fordwagen`
```

How can I get all the three lists for names, ages and salaries in a single SQL not to have three database calls?

Comment: What is your purpose in avoiding three database calls? What are you trying to optimize?

Comment: Network, database sessions, cleaner code etc...

Comment: There is no necessary connection between the number SQL statements one writes and any of those things. You want us to spend our time helping you: the least you can do is invest some of your time framing a decent question. Please explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: 1. I do not want to spend time for networking by going database for each list, actually I have mpre then ten lists.

Comment: 2. I do not want to hit database many times for the same page even if I use use connection pooling.

Comment: 3. I need to create different methods for different database calls and I do not want to make changes in many places in case os a requirent change.

Comment: This is a generic need and I wanted this to be available to public and people make use of it. Dont you thing getting datatable filters in an efficient way is good to know?

Comment: As a database professional I find "generic" to be a trigger word. The world is full of terrible models executed in the name of genericism. Obviously I am in favour of efficiency but I often find people use the word to mean many different things. That's why I asked you for your particular measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will there be that many duplicate names? A company full of Mr. and Mrs. Smith? Probably not.

So simply

```
select first_name, last_name, age, salary from employees;
```

to get, say 1000 employee records, rather than 250 first names, 700 last names, 30 ages and 120 salaries. Then loop through the records in your app and you are done with as little traffic as possible.

Comment: It is expected to have more than 6000 records at a time, so having a couple of "John Smith"s is quite possible.

Comment: Still, I think my percentages should not be too far of the mark. Some 70% distinct last names, 25% distinct first names... Well, just count to see for yourself :-)

Comment: Ohh, now I got your point. Yeah this looks like a very efficient way to do this, especially when we have more than 100k items to query and get the distinct values out of that a lot of times, I will test this for my app since not sure if database distinct operator is faster than my loops.

Comment: this looks the most efficient way to do this and it can be easily implemented in many different languages/platforms without adding new constructs to your app like db caching etc.. which will convert the debugging to a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

```
select name as filter_value, 'name_filter' as filter_type from employee group by name
union
select ages as filter_value, 'age_filter' as filter_type from employee group by ages
union
select salary as filter_value, 'salary_filter' as filter_type from employee group by salary
```

The group by will have the same effect as distinct, you can use either syntax.  This gives you a list of as `filter_value` and `filter type`.  Populate each filter list by the correct `filter_type`.

Hope I got what you're asking here right...comment if I'm off

Comment: Column aliases are not literals, they don't take single quotes.

Comment: Don't use `GROUP BY` when you mean `DISTINCT`. You are not aggregating, you are only removing duplicates. Then use `TO_CHAR` to have the queries return the same datatype; else you'll get `ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I do not want to spend time for networking by going database for each list, actually I have more then ten lists.

The amount of network traffic - the number of packets - will be broadly the same whether you issue ten separate calls or one combined call.

> 2. I do not want to hit database many times on the same page even if I use connection pooling.

Okay. But that's more a matter of how you design your application tier.

> 3. I need to create different methods for different database calls and I do not want to make changes in many places in case of a requirement change.

it seems you have an unusual understanding of "cleaner code". The Single Responsibility Principle (the *S* in SOLID) is the foundation stone of clean code. Having ten methods each of which does one thing is cleaner than one method which does ten things.

Perhaps what you need is a cache? If the target table for filters is relatively slowly changing then result set caching could be highly effective. Oracle supports caching - with built-in invalidation - in both the database and the client side. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/k/stmtcach.htm). Even if your target table does change frequently maybe you can maintain tables of filters which are more static.